# subsetting and multiple plotting

Tags: r, histogram, subset

I got a large data file (58 columns, 27,000 rows) which I tried to subset by one variable (Year - of 30 levels), then histogram another variable (calenday) for each of the 30 categories. I tried several options.

First I tried the 'apply' functions, defining "hist" as my FUN;

```
    >tapply(calenday,Year,hist(calenday,main=unique(Year)))
```

but this left me with only one graph.

Then I tried to loop it. I tried several ways of subsetting my dataframe, then applying a for loop on the histogram function, but it didn't work. I got only one graph at the best.

I then tried the lattice condiotonal "histogram" command:

```
     >histogram(~calenday|factor(Year))
```

but 30 graphs stacked together is a bit too much.

SO I tried looping it:

```
     for (i in 1984:2013) {   
         histogram(~calenday | Year, subset=(Year==i), br=28,    
         main=paste("plot of", i), type="count")}
```

but again nothing came through, although no error message was given.
I read somewhere that there is a problem with plots once you write it as a script function, but I couldn't figure out how to solve it (no solution worked).

Eventually, I simply tried:

```
    tapply(calenday,Year,hist)
```

and this did work, but the graphs produced were ofcoarse very basic, with titles as numbers, too wide breaks, etc.

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your data, and the plots, it's a bit of guesswork from my side.

However, I would've used `ggplot` and it's excellent `facet_grid()` and `facet_wrap()` functions.

Take a look at this documentation and see if the charts are similar to your needs.

http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/facet_grid.html

Good luck

Comment: Thank you Jon! I'll look at it. I am new to R, and thought this should be a simple task...

Comment: Hopefully, and probably, it is simple. Try to create a reproducable mini-version of your problem, with some data in the same structure, then it would be easier to progress.